# modal window places form data on querystring after close

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a MVC3 site that produces a modal window with security questions.  The problem is, when the ajax call comes back, whether success or error and the modal window is closed, all the form data ends up on the querystring of the parent window

```
$(this).dialog('destroy');
```

**and**

```
 $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
```

**and**

```
and placing close: function () { $(this).dialog('destroy'); },
```

in the dialog instantiation with zero success.

How do I prevent the modal window from passing the form values to the Parent windows querystring?

**Partial View that appears in modal window**

```
   <div id="resetpanel">
    <form name="pwreset" id="pwreset" action="" method="post">
        Account Number: <input type="text" name="acctNumber" id="acctNumber" /><br />
        <button class="btn" name="btnNext" onclick="goResetValidate();return false;">Next</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="challengepanel">
    <form name="challenge" id="challenge" style="display:none;" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="setNum" id="setNum" value="" />
        Member Number: <input type="text" name="acctNumber2" id="acctNumber2" readonly="true" /><br />
        <label id="Q0"></label>
        Answer: <input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer1" /><br />
        <label id="Q1"></label>
        Answer: <input type="text" name="answer2" id="answer2" /><br />
        <label id="Q2"></label>
        Answer: <input type="text" name="answer3" id="answer3" /><br />
        <button class="btn" name="btnNext" id="challengebutton" onclick="goResetPassword();return false;">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**AJAX calls with Jquery**

```
//function that captures the account number and sends them to the service for processing        
    function goResetValidate() {

        // check that all answers are numbers only on challenge questions
        var ruleset = {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true
                    };
        $('#pwreset').validate({
            rules: {
                qSet0: ruleset,
                qSet1: ruleset,
                qSet2: ruleset
                    }
         });

        // challenge questions for password reset
        var qSet0 = ["Please enter the numeral of the month you were born (i.e. January = 1, February = 2)", "Please enter the last 4 digits of your Social Security number (i.e. 444-55-XXXX)", "Please enter your home zip code - first five digits only (i.e. 22333)."];
        var qSet1 = ["Please enter the day of the month you were born (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.).", "Please enter the 2 middle digits of your Social Security number (i.e. 444-XX-6666).", "Please enter the last 4 digits of your home telephone number (i.e. 703-555-XXXX)."];
        var qSet2 = ["Please enter the first 3 digits of your Social Security number (i.e. XXX-55-6666).", "Please enter the 3 middle digits of your home telephone (i.e. 703-XXX-5555).", "Please enter your home zip code - first five digits only (i.e. 22333)."];
        // rand for choice of questions
        var random = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3) - 1);
        var jRequest = {};
        var acnum = $("#acctNumber").val();
        jRequest.an = acnum;

        var jData = {};
        jData.request = jRequest;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: ResetValidateUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(jData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (splashObj) {
                switch (splashObj.ResetValidateResult.RESPONSE) {
                    case "VALID":
                        var challengequestiondisplayed = splashObj.ResetValidateResult.RESPONSE;
                        var quest = "qSet" + random;
                        // remove reset form
                        $('#resetpanel').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            $('#resetpanel').remove();
                            $('#acctNumber2').val(acnum);
                            $('#setNum').val(random);
                        });
                        $.each(eval(quest), function (index, item) {
                            $('#Q' + index).text("" + this + "");
                        });
                        $('form#challenge').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
                        break;
                    // bad member number              
                    case "INVALID":
                        alert("We're sorry; the system did not recognize the Member Number entered. Please try again.");
                        break;
                    // no email on file       
                    case "NO_EMAIL":
                        alert("This feature requires a valid email in the system.  Please contact us to provide a valid email address.");
                        break;
                    // error       
                    case "ERROR":
                        alert("We're sorry; the system was uanble to complete your request. We apologize for the inconvenience.");
                        break;
                    // system is in memo-post mode       
                    case "MEMO_POST":
                        alert("The system is unavailable at this time.  Please try your request again later.");
                        break;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("A Password Web Service Error!");
                //$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
            }
        });
    }
```

//function that captures the account number/qeustins set number/answers and sends them to the service for processing
        function goResetPassword() {

```
        var jRequest = {};
        jRequest.an = $("#acctNumber2").val();
        jRequest.setNumber = $("#setNum").val();
        jRequest.answer1 = $("#answer1").val();
        jRequest.answer2 = $("#answer2").val();
        jRequest.answer3 = $("#answer3").val();

        var jData = {};
        jData.request = jRequest;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: ResetPasswordUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(jData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (splashObj) {
                switch (splashObj.ResetPasswordResult.RESPONSE) {
                    // error       
                    case "ERROR":
                        alert("We're sorry; the system was uanble to complete your request. We apologize for the inconvenience.");
                        break;
                    // system is in memo-post mode       
                    case "MEMO_POST":
                        alert("The system is unavailable at this time.  Please try your request again later.");
                        break;
                    case "INVALID_RESPONSE":
                        alert("We're sorry; we are unable to validate your status as the NetBranch account holder based upon your answers to the security questions. Note: The information requested is based upon member data currently on file with Apple FCU. If you continue to encounter difficulties with the security questions, please contact.");
                        break;
                    case "PERM_FROZEN":
                        alert("We're sorry; For security reasons, your online account access has been disabled. We apologize for the inconvenience.");
                        break;
                    case "FROZE_NOW":
                        alert("We're sorry; we are unable to validate your status as the NetBranch account holder. For security purposes, your account has been locked. We apologize for the inconvenience. To restore access, please contact ");
                        break;
                    case "SUCCESS":
                        alert("A temporary password has been sent to the email we have on file.");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("Password Web Service Error!");
                $.dialog('close').remove;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Modal Window Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).dialog('destroy'); },
                    modal: true,
                    width: '530px'
                })
                .load(this.href);
    });

    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Comment: Try messing with the button element's type attribute (button, submit). From memory the button element inside a form can behave oddly in some browsers if you don't specify a type. If this fixes it, I'll repost as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Listen, I dont get your question, but still, I will try to address your problem,

```
$("#my-form-div").dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  width: 600,
  height: 600,
  modal: true,
  draggable:true,
  resizable:false,
  title: 'FORM',
  buttons: [
       {
            text: "CLOSE",
            className: 'close-button-class',
            click: function() {
                // do what ever you want on the close event
                $(this).dialog("close");
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    ],
  open: function() {
    //do whatever you want on the open event.
    $("#my-form-div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('form_view')) %>");
    }
});
```

Please be more clear about what you want.

Comment: I apologize if i wasn't explicit.  A modal window opens with a partial view and displays an input field that takes a usernumber.  The onclick of a button in that modal window checks that number in a Db using an Ajax call.  If they fail i alert and then close the modal window.  The modal window is sending the number and button name through to the parent in the querystring.  I want to prevent the data from getting paased on the parents address.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhhhh found it.  I needed to put a method of POST on the form to prevent it from defaulting.  I guess even though I was just closing the dialog box, the form was submitting itself as the default GET.